# What is the right solution if I need lots of id and classes when creating a Jquery popup box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, In my website admin panel I've users.php page where I've to send more request to server using Jquery/Ajax. when I send this request to server I need to show **pop up box** for e.g. edit user details, resend confirmation password, send login details, etc.... using **jQuery Modals**  (You can see the popup plugin here..http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin)

**So following is the popup box code:**

Here i use `$i`. It's means it increment the $i = 0 / 1/ 2 and so one.... base on sql query result..So the Id is ok for now but here I need different class'es like reveal-modal1, reveal-modal2, reveal-modal3 and so on based on sql query result. So my question, is it now require to create more class'es in the style sheet base on sql result or Is there any solution which just need only one class or id ?

```
<div id="myModal<?php echo $i; ?>" class="reveal-modal3" style="width:90%; margin:a auto; 
color:#FFF; visibility: hidden;">
// my popup data....
</div>
```

**Note:** Now I'm using. reveal-modal3, reveal-modal4 etc..in my css style sheet but I think that is not right way to do this. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Do you mean that $i can be 1 but also can be for example 10? I don't think its smart then to use css. Use CSS to define the global styles of the popup boxes (with a class), then jQuery to give it specific styles. Otherwise everytime you add a modal in the database, you also have to add a class/id in the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal1">
        Popup 1
    </a>    

    <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal2">
        Popup 2
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal3">
        Popup 3
    </a>

    <div id="myModal1" class="reveal-modal">
        <h1>Reveal Modal Goodness -1</h1>
        <p>This is a default modal in all its glory, but any of the styles here can easily be changed in the CSS.</p>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal2" class="reveal-modal">
        <h1>Reveal Modal Goodness -2</h1>
        <p>This is a default modal in all its glory, but any of the styles here can easily be changed in the CSS.</p>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal3" class="reveal-modal">
        <h1>Reveal Modal Goodness -3</h1>
        <p>This is a default modal in all its glory, but any of the styles here can easily be changed in the CSS.</p>
        <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>
```

Class would be common for all popup box. You need to keep unique id for individual popup that can be increase

Answer (score 1):

Anything wrong with `class="reveal-modal reveal-modal1"`, thereby allowing you to have individual classes per ID while still having a single, *static* `reveal-modal` class that applies to all of them? ;)

Generally speaking, `class` attributes should always be static, there should not be an incrementing number on the end...

Comment: Agreeing with this one here, and adding that you could generate random UUIDs for every popup.

Comment: @quantyc "random" and "UUID" don't really go together :p

Comment: sorry, I meant randomly generated UUID.